# Apply style to div but not <strong> child

Tags: html, css

How can I possibly apply a style to a parent `div` but not the `<strong>` child. I've tried various ways of `:not` selector but none of my tries succeeded.

Here's what I came up with

```css
.total:not(strong) {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">Baloons <strong>$3.75</strong></div>
<div class="total">Pens <strong>$1.99</strong></div>
```

I know I can do apply the styles to those separately but I am looking for a `:not` way of doing it so I can do it on one line.

I also know I can give `<strong>` a class and do `.total:not(.strong-class)` but why doesn't it work the way I try it originally?

Comment: You cant. You're not selecting all `.total` which are `not()` the element `strong`. You need a `.total >strong{color: black;}`

Comment: color is inherited so you are not applying it to strong but strong is inherting it and you cannot avoid this unless you specify a different style for strong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:not` rule refers to the target element. Your rule `.total:not(strong)` is translated to apply the styles (`color: gray`) to an element with class `.total`, which is not a `strong` node (the `<strong>` tag). Since the `.total` node is `div`, the rule still applies.

Reset the strong's color to initial or choose a different color:

```css
.total {
  color: gray;
}

.total strong {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">Baloons <strong>$3.75</strong></div>
<div class="total">Pens <strong>$1.99</strong></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the default css of `color` in the element `strong`.
`.total:not(strong) {` works fine, but the default `color` is `gray` too!

[:not](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

```css
*{color:blue}
.total:not(strong) {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">Baloons <strong>$3.75</strong></div>
<div class="total">Pens <strong>$1.99</strong></div>
```

Comment: the default color isn't grey

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.total {
  color: red;
}

.total strong {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">Baloons <strong>$3.75</strong></div>
<div class="total">Pens <strong>$1.99</strong></div>
```